# how to create sitemap using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want create sitemap. I use zend framwork. I dont know much about sitemap. any one knows how to create sitemap in zend framework

Comment: Maybe start by reading http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Comment: did you a least google `zend framework sitemap` ?

Comment: @bensiu above search brought me here

Comment: zend framework almost totally lacks documentation. After working with a Zend Framework project for good over 2 years, we opted to migrate away. I couldn't tell you how to do it or where to find good resources on your problem. The only thing that comes to my mind is hiring an expensive ZF expert. My advice: Don't use ZF, use Laravel - if you can

Answer (score 0):

[There is a zend cast about this](http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_navigation-dynamically-creating-a-menu-a-sitemap-and-breadcrumbs/2009/06/)